# Cascade delete doesn't work on User

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that has ForeignKey to User:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

When I try to delete user, I get exception:

```
IntegrityError: update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint
```

So should I delete all MyModel objects manually before I delete user? How can I do that?

Comment: set `user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)` then try deleting MyModel